# Firefox menu is missing

Tags: firefox, menu, preferences

I have just installed Ubuntu 12 and started up Firefox so I could configure it.  But there doesn't seem to be any way to access preferences.  No menu bar appears at the top.  right-clicking (in multiple places) doesn't seem to work either, no option to open the preferences window is available.  Nothing seems to work.  All I can do is change my home page by dragging the URL onto the Home button.  Help!

Comment: Is it 12.10 or 12.04?

Answer (score 10):

It's a little late, but I faced this problem with Firefox 51.0.1 after updating it from 44.0.2.

Problem: The new Firefox seems to have the menu bar as part of the window itself and does not use the top menu bar of Unity.

Solution: If you can't see it then it is probably hidden, **key in `F10` to make it visible** and (optionally) check **View -> Toolbars -> Menu Bar** to keep it visible.

Note that the usual `Alt` key for this purpose brings up the application specific launcher in Unity, hence the `F10` alternative.

Comment: I had this issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 and this solution worked for me. `Alt` does bring up the Firefox menu bar if you press it just a little bit longer.

Comment: After upgrading Firefox from 84.0 to 85.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, the menu bar disappeared & this worked but now the menu bar is always within the Firefox window instead of at the top of the screen like all the other applications are. Not a big deal but I wonder if there's a way to put it at the top?

Answer (score 5):

This is the only solution that works.

> Navigate to about:config, search for 'unity', and toggle from true to
>   false.
>
> That did it for me just now.
>
> (the full preference name is ui.use_unity_menubar)

See: [Global menu bar integration add-on missing in Firefox 22 for Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312940/global-menu-bar-integration-add-on-missing-in-firefox-22-for-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu Unity, the menu is in the top dark bar (the panel). You should put the cursor there, then click Edit, and then Preferences.

If the menu stills don't work, try installing the last updates by opening the **Update Manager** and updating all the packages listed there. After updating, restart the computer and start firefox again. The problem should be fixed if you follow this steps, but if it still doesn't work, you can submitting a bug on Launchpad.

I hope it gets fixed!

Comment: @okinawa_dato Alternatively you can also press the `Alt` button on your keyboard to activate the HUD and search for any menu entries within Firefox. Same thing goes for any other application Ubuntu ships with.

Answer (score 3):

I just upgraded from 11.## to 12.10 and noticed the same missing menu links.  After a few minutes of reading I decided to check on keyboard short cuts, lo and behold F10 displays menu options when hover mouse over web page description/name top left.

Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_windows-tabs

Toggle Full Screen  F11
Toggle Menu Bar (when hidden)   Alt (KDE)
F10 (GNOME)

Comment: Needed this for Waterfox.

Answer (score 1):

By default the menu is hidden...

[image: When there is no cursor on the title-bar]

Menu appears when you hover the cursor over the title-baar...
[image: Cursor on the title-bar...]

Comment: And how can I make it appear permanently.

Comment: No.. I am not sure but I think there is no option in de default theme.... you need some software that allows to configure the theme/appearance like Unity. I am also not sure if Unity allows to make it permanent or not...

But please post it here if you are able to make it permanent in the future... :)

Comment: I found the solution shortly after this post. I had to go to about:config and set ui.use_unity_menubar to false.

Comment: My Firefox has no such option "ui.use_unity_menubar"... any idea?

Comment: Try to add this attribute in about:config by right click->new boolean -> ui.use_unity_menubar -> value -> false.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after disabling all the annoying Ubuntu menu bar hacks. It seems the set the menu bar to hidden in Firefox by default too (otherwise I guess you'd get two menu bars). The solution is:

1. Click on the "hamburger" options menu (right of the search box).
2. Click "+ Customise" at the bottom
3. Click "Show/Hide Toolbars" at the bottom left
4. Click "Menu Bar"

Answer (score 0):

For me, Firefox menu strangely does NOT appear on the panel (unlike almost all other applications). The first time I ran Firefox (that is today!) I didn't see any menus either. But this is a simple problem to fix. Just drag the window down a little bit and the menu will show up. The firefox menu is not on the panel, but instead part of the firefox window itself. It is probably just hidden below your top panel and that's why you don't see it.

Comment: Then you should maximize the window, maybe then it should work.

Comment: I just restarted my computer, after updating firefox, and its menubar is now on the top panel as expected.

Comment: Yay, updating usually solves a lot of problems :)

Comment: You should include your comment as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox - in the top-left corner there is a 'Firefox'-button (red) - click on it - go to options and select 'Show menu'.

After that, I think you should now see what you want to see.