# Global menu bar integration add-on missing in Firefox 22 for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, firefox, appmenu

I just installed Firefox 22 via PPA, and during installation I noticed the global menu bar integration add-on version 22 also was included, but when I launch Firefox I cannot locate the add-on to disable it.  In version 21 it was there, and I did disable it because I do not like to have the menus in the menu bar, but rather have the Firefox button next to the tabs.

I did search for an answer, but didn't find anything most likely because version 22 just came out.  I removed the add-on via terminal's purge command, and it completed successfully, but after reboot the menu's are still in the menu bar.  I also completely removed Firefox via Synaptic, installed the Software Center version, and was able to disable the add-on as before, so I re-downloaded 22, but again it's not found.

I then looked for the add-on to see if it was installed, and it was, but it's not visible within the add-on themselves.  I noticed on the global menu bar integration PPA page it states as of version 22 is no longer supported, so I'm confused.  How do either remove this add-on to get the Firefox button back by the tabs, or make it so I can disable it in the add-on's page within Firefox?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Navigate to `about:config`, search for 'unity', and toggle from true to false.

That did it for me just now.

(the full preference name is `ui.use_unity_menubar`)

Comment: @gertvdijk You are awesome!  I spent two hours trying to figure that out.  Thank you!

Comment: @BobbyPhoenix It's [Too Early](http://askubuntu.com/users/170420/too-early) who provided the answer - I just edited it a little. ;) Credits go to him.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks for the clarification.  @Too Early you are awesome!  Well both of you are as you both are quick to help.  Thank you both.  :-)

Comment: Thanks buddy. The rest of the internet is giving absolutely useless solutions.