# Firefox-like Global Menu Integration

Tags: unity, firefox, globalmenu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. The original Firefox integrate with Unity perfectly. I want to use [Palemoon](http://www.palemoon.org), but unfortunately, it has no integration with unity/global menu. I tried to look at the default plugin/add-ons on Firefox, but the "Unity Integration" add-on description is just for web apps and not global menu. I even tried downloading vanilla Firefox from Mozilla site, but it doesn't integrate either with Unity, even with the same add-ons.

I saw this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312940/global-menu-bar-integration-add-on-missing-in-firefox-22-for-ubuntu-12-04), but it seems Palemoon nor vanilla Firefox doesn't have `ui.use_unity_menubar`.

So I'm wondering where can I see the code for that. Is Canonical hardcode it into Firefox source? Is there a way to see it?

Comment: I have this problem too, is there any solution?
It works for firefox but not palemoon by default.